# put values in arrays with identical values

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm pretty new to swift and I'm working on app with a collectionview. I like to order all images with the same tag in the same section. So i have to have arrays with images with the same tag.
Example main array with following values:

- Image1 with tag a
- Image2 with tag b
- Image3 with tag b
- Image4 with tag a
- Image5 with tag c
- ...

As result I like to have following arrays: one with tag a and one array with tag b, and so on.

I have found an function(thanks to stackoverflow) to get all the distinct value from the main array. I have used this for the number of sections. It is as following:

```
 func uniq<S: SequenceType, E: Hashable where E==S.Generator.Element>(seq: S) -> [E] {
    var seen: [S.Generator.Element:Int] = [:]
    return filter(seq) { seen.updateValue(1, forKey: $0) == nil }
}
```

I know you have to go through the main array.
I've been spending some thinking on this mather but I can't find an nice solution except this not working code

```
var distinctArray=uniq(main_array)

//CREATE ARRAYS FOR ALL DISTINCT VALUES
for var index = 0; index < distinctArray.count; index++ {
   var "\(distinctArray[index])" = []
   //I KNOW THIS WILL NOT WORK BUT HOW DO YOU DO THIS, GIVE AN ARRAY A NAME OF A VALUE OF AN ARRAY?
}

//GOING THROUGH THE ARRAY AND ADD THE VALUE TO THE RIGHT ARRAY
for var index = 0; index < main_array.count; index++ {
   for var index2 = 0; index2 < distinctArray.count; index2+=1{
   if main_array[index]==distinctArray[index2]{
      "\(distinctArray[index])".append(main_array[index])
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone give me an hint? Maybe i'm on the wrong path with the previous non-working code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you want is to create a new dictionary, with the key being the tag and the array being the images with that tag:

```
struct Image {
    let name: String
    let tag: String
}

let imageArray = [
    Image(name: "Image1", tag: "a"),
    Image(name: "Image2", tag: "b"),
    Image(name: "Image3", tag: "b"),
    Image(name: "Image4", tag: "a"),
    Image(name: "Image5", tag: "c"),
]

func bucketImagesByTag(images: [Image]) -> [String:[Image]] {
    var buckets: [String:[Image]] = [:]
    for image in images {
        // dictionaries and arrays being value types, this 
        // is unfortunately not as efficient as it might be...
        buckets[image.tag] = (buckets[image.tag] ?? []) + [image]
    }
    return buckets
}

// will return a dictionary with a: and b: having 
// arrays of two images, and c: a single image
bucketImagesByTag(imageArray)
```

If you wanted to make this generic, you could write a function that took a collection, and a function that identified the key to bucket by, and returned a dictionary from the key to arrays of elements.

```
func bucketBy<S: SequenceType, T>(source: S, by: S.Generator.Element -> T) -> [T:[S.Generator.Element]] {
    var buckets: [T:[S.Generator.Element]] = [:]
    for element in source {
        let key = by(element)
        buckets[key] = (buckets[key] ?? []) + [element]
    }
    return buckets
}

// same as bucketImagesByTag above
bucketBy(imageArray) { $0.tag }
```

Interestingly, the fact that `T` is being used to key the returned dictionary means Swift can infer that it must be hashable, so you don’t have to explicitly require it unlike with `uniq`.